# Parsing time from C++ DLL to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, epoch

I'm writing a C++ DLL which will be accessed using MATLAB's `loadlibrary`. I need a specific function to return the current time in **milliseconds** precision, and parse it correctly in matlab. Specifically i'll need to extract the year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

I currently have something like

```
long long time_since_epoch()
{
    return std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

which MATLAB calls using `t = calllib('myDLL', 'time_since_epoch');`.

Then I tried parsing it using `dt = datetime(t, 'convertfrom', 'epochtime');`, which didn't work.

But, I compared it with the time given from `posixtime(datetime)` and found out I'm getting a correct answer by using `dt = datetime(t / 10000000, 'convertfrom', 'epochtime');`, which is very odd.

I don't fully understand what's going on here, and I somehow lost the milliseconds  in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your `system_clock` is not counting milliseconds, it is counting something finer than a millisecond.  Exactly what isn't important because you can specifically ask for the count in milliseconds:

```
long long time_since_epoch()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count();
}
```